# Why is fundamental principle of counting applicable for finite events?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, permutations

The statement of the *fundamental principle of counting* is "*if an event can occur in m different ways, following which another event can occur in n different ways, then the total number of occurrence of the event in the given order is m×n.*" However, in my textbook the next line says "*the above principle can be generalized for any **finite** number of events.*" Why can't we continue it to infinite number of terms?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about the error.

Comment: Your welcome :-)

Comment: Who says we can't?  It's still true for infinitely many events.  However, you have to define infinite products, and maybe the textbook isn't interested in doing that at this stage.

Comment: That might be the case. Thankyou for the answer.